# Query the structure field with the user input in C

Tags: c

I am experimenting a new thing in C to convert the user input string to the structure field and then obtain the value of it.

```
typedef struct {
  int ant;
  char str[50];

}Sample;

main ()
    {
       Sample a = { 1, "hi" };
       char query[50];
       scanf ("enter the query object inside the Sample structure %s", query );

       /* Search and print function */
       ex : now my query is for field ant 
       How do I convert the query string input "ant" to a.ant and print the value of ant ?
    }
```

Please pardon me If I am not clear in my explanation.

```
Input : ant  Output : 1
Input: str   Output : hi
INput: rat   Output: Field not present
```

Comment: What's wrong with `scanf("%d", &(a.ant));`?

Comment: Are you saying if user input is `"ant"`, then you want to print the value of `a.ant`?

Comment: Post examples: pairs of text input and expected results.

Comment: please explain your question, what it is about ??

Comment: I have edited my question . Please check.

Comment: Sourav. My structures are not as simple as above mentioned in my question. It is highly complex with lot of arrays and nested structures.

Comment: @vip  I think you need to divide and conquer else you are asking for a general purpose data base engine.  Step 1, Get user input as text.  Step 2) parse input input into a query type based on variable name, {array index, member names}, (this part recursively) and step 3) accessing the data based on the query.  Perhaps steps 2/3 could be recursively.  All in all  this may be 10 to 100s of time more code than posted here given the far-reaching "It is highly complex with lot of arrays and nested structures".  If this is too much, perhaps C is not the target language for your task.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user for the member name and then selectivity print its contents.

Lots of additional possibilities to detect/ignore leading/trailing white-space, case insensitivity, EOF handling, etc., especially given the post's scant details.

```
   char query[50];
   puts("enter the query object inside the Sample structure");
   fgets(query, sizeof query, stdin);
   // trim potential \n
   query[strcspn(query, "\n")] = 0;

   if (strcmp(query, "ant")== 0) {
     printf("%d\n", a.amt);
   } else if (strcmp(query, "str")== 0) {
     printf("%s\n", a.str); 
   } else {
     puts("Field not present"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to search the name and find the integer value on that name if it exists. this is how you can do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct {
  int ant;
  char str[50];

}Sample;

 void  main ()
    {
       Sample a = { 1, "hi" };
       char query[50];
       printf("enter the query object inside the Sample structure: ");
       scanf ("%s", query );
        if(strcmp(a.str,query)==0) printf("Matched values is %d\n",a.ant);
        else printf("Not found\n");



}
```

Comment: what is the output if my input is ant? I don't think above solution works

Comment: ant is a variable name.  Your variable value is hi. So if you enter hi. you will get the value "1" allocated with your structure. I read your edited question now and I noticed you want to query a string with an integer. I dont  understand what you mean by that. Myabe you will have to give a more complex example and show where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Nirvedh. All I need is a way to convert the user input query string to a variable name and get the value of the variable. If my input  is "ant" i need to get the value of variable ant. If my input is "str", i need to get the value of char str[] .

Comment: @vip " my input is "ant" i need to get the value of variable ant." is unclear.  Posted code has variable `a`.  Variable `a` has an `int`  _member_ `amt`.  Sounds like you want "If my input is `"ant"` , I need to get the value of `a.ant`".